# Android Design Support Lib: how to hide toolbar after scrolling some distance?

Tags: android, toolbar

i've implemented the show/hide effect with `CoordinatorLayout/AppBarLayout/Toolbar/RecyclerView`. what i want now is, the toolbar will remain its position right when i start scrolling up, and start hiding only when i scroll up some distance, i.e., 50dp or 2/3/4/etc items of the `RecyclerView`.

if i implements `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener` interface, i must show/hide the toolbar with animation: `mToolbar.animate().translationY(-mToolbar.getHeight())`, which is NOT what i want.

what i want is the brand new Android Design Support Library, i.e., `CoordinatorLayout`, `AppBarLayout`, etc.

Comment: I think you can use `app:layout_scrollFlags` flag in Toolbar!

Comment: yes, i've set it, otherwise i won't hide toolbar. what i want is one step ahead - scroll a certain distance.